# Unable to access qBittorrent Web UI when starting the service as another user

Tags: openvpn, qbittorrent

Merry Christmas friends!

Spent about 5 hours to find a solution to this issue, and i'm about to go nuts..

I followed this [guide](https://www.htpcguides.com/force-torrent-traffic-vpn-split-tunnel-ubuntu-14-04/) to created a split tunnel, and assigned the tun0 to a "vpn" user in Ubuntu. Which actually works, I logged into the user and did a `curl ipinfo.io` to test the vpn connection. So the split tunnel works just fine.

The qBittorrent is accessible when i use my regular user in the 
[qBittorrent-nox.service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HltJk.png) file.

But not when I replace my regular username with "vpn". I suspect it's permission issues, but I did add the vpn user to sudo group, my regular user to the vpn group.

When I do a `curl localhost:8080`, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhGnK.png)

I tried my very best to get this working, but I really don't know what to do now...

Comment: "_When I do a curl `localhost:8080`, I get this_" - Is this with qBittorrent running under the `vpn` user? That looks like it's working properly, unless it's not accepting the password or something (?) - is that the case, or do you just get an "unable to connect" in your browser? I don't know the answer to your question, but, once you do get it running, there is a magnet link at [https://ipleak.net/](https://ipleak.net/)which you can load into your torrent client to verify that VPN is working _in the torrent client_, in case you want to check.

Comment: The browser tells me it's unreachable. Tried with chrome, firefox etc. When I change it back to my regular user, I have access to the web interface without issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay, Got it working! 
Seems like the problem was within the `iptables.sh` file.

I changed the:

> export LOCALIP="192.168.1.60"

to

> export LOCALIP="192.168.1.0/24"

Which makes any devices within 192.168.1.0 subnet, able to reach the Web UI.